# how to prevent multiple request in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a contact us endpoint in my Nodejs which gets a formData from frontend and it will store the formData in my database. If someone use an application such as postman or whatever, can target my endpoint buy sending multiple request with same formData! I don't have authentication on my app so i cant put any condition on it.

```
router.post("/", upload.none(), async (req, res) => {
  console.log("req", req.body);
  if (!req.body) {
    res.send({ success: false, msg: "Cannot send blank message!" });
    return;
  }
  let body = JSON.parse(req.body.contact);
  if (!body.email || !body.message || !body.subject) {
    res.send({ success: false, msg: "Mandatory fields are not filled!" });
    return;
  }
  try {
    await getDb("messages").insertOne({
      name: body.name,
      email: body.email,
      phone: body.phone,
      subject: body.subject,
      message: body.message,
    });

    res.send(
      JSON.stringify({
        success: true,
        msg: "Message has been sent successfully",
      })
    );
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
    res.send(JSON.stringify({ success: false, msg: err }));
  }
});

export default router;
```

Comment: You would need the store some state about the person who submitted the form, think an object with a list of IP addresses (or a real database if you want it to persist). When the user's data is successfully added to the database store a key in the object with that user. Make sure to check if they've successfully submitted data before you call `insertOne`. Not too insane.

Comment: Thanks for the respond, i was planning to separate the backend from frontend, with this idea i am not sure if i get the IP from node it will give my frontend ip or user ip? i might need to exclude my frontend ip, right?